# How to include additional application info in swagger file?

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

I'm running Symfony 4 API Platform in combination with redoc (instead of swagger) but still bassed on the swagger.yaml file that api platform export.

The goal would be to add x-logo and other aditional api info to the swagger file

I'm currently adding it manualy to to yaml file but would like it to be included in the automated php bin/console api:swagger:export --output=openapi.yaml --yaml export

Comment: Maybe a [Swagger Decorator](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/swagger/#overriding-the-openapi-specification) can do that